# Is it possible to use textbackground() function in VS 2008?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2008

I want to use this function in a c++ program written in visual studio 2008.
As far as I know Borland used to support this function but it's not a standard c++ function and the VS 2008 doesn't identify this code:

```
textbackground(1);
```

I wanted to know if there is any solution to use this function in VS 2008 ?

You can read more about this function [here](http://www.ousob.com/ng/borcpp/ng6c57c.php).

P.S. including conio.h doesn't work

Comment: You want a function that will change the text's background color?  What background? A GUI's? A terminal's?  Have you tried anything?

Comment: Where is the documentation for this function? That will probably tell you which headers you need to include and which libraries you need to link with.

Comment: @infact, it appears to be part of conio.h on certain platforms: http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devwin32/coniohpart_xml.html

Comment: @chembrad, I added a link above.It explains about the function.Actually I want to change the color of the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is to use the Console IO functions of Windows NT.

E.g. SetConsoleTextAttribute sets attributes of the text (foreground color, background color) on the console.  [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686047(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686047%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) describes this function.  On [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686974(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686974%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you can find example code using this console function (and other console functions).

Comment: Thank you.It worked fine :) just another question, so you mean there is NO way to use the exact textbackground() function?

Comment: Probably not.  I think textbackground is a function that is defined by the runtime libraries of the Borland compiler.  If you switch compiler, you get other runtimes and libraries (although the standard C library remains the same, but this function isn't in the standard C library).  By using these Windows functions, you can now switch to any C compiler running on Windows, so this function isn't tied to the runtime of a specific compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Just to help others a bit more:

Instead of:

```
textbackground(1);
```

I used **SetConsoleTextAttribute()** function in this way:

```
# include <windows.h>

HANDLE screen;

int main( )
    { 
       screen = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
       SetConsoleTextAttribute(screen,1);

       // your own code

       return 0;
     }
```

number **1** refers to the color **BLUE**.